# Best replacer for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

So as we know Ubuntu One is sadly getting shut down.
I was really happy with Ubuntu One. Instantly syncing my files and with generous 5GB of storage!
Now the question is, what software have you guys used to replace U1? 
I was using U1 on three devices (my ubundu desktop,my mobile and my wifes mobile)
The instant syncing was really nice and it was really user friendly.

Any suggestions out there? What are you using?
Is dropbox the software to go with on this?

Thanks on beforehand for any comments!
I greatly appreciate the help
(Off-topic Loving my Ubuntu desktop and the community is just awesome)
~Beef

Comment: I could get Copy to act more like U1 did than I could any of the others, and documented it at http://www.hackcraft.net/u12copy/ some people won't care about the differences or even prefer the way another service works, but if you were used to the way U1 worked, you might find that useful.